# Find the nearest vehicle position in C# .NET console app

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I seem to fail to read the dat file as a result I 'm stuck and cant move on from there. I believe there is someone who worked with something like this and could actually help me go through this hell.

When I read the.dat file it returns some weird text like this one below:

```
"UT\0�\bBv7��\u0015��a\0\0\0\0\u0002\0\0\0U2-100"
```

I just pasted the instruction in the description above and the links to the zip files.

> In the link below you will find a binary data file which contains a
> position for each of 2 million vehicles. Your task is to write a
> program that can find the nearest vehicle position in the data file to
> each of the 10 co - ordinates provided below. In addition to being
> able to do this, however, your program must be able to complete all 10
> lookups in less time than our benchmark.This benchmark is based on
> simply looping through each of the 2 million positions and keeping the
> closest to each given co - ordinate. This is simply repeated for each
> of the 10 provided co - ordinates. The challenge set to you is to
> think of a more efficient way to achieve this and to implement it.
>
> The challenge is is in C# & .NET

Dat File and benchmark zip file:

- [VehiclePositions_DataFile](https://app.box.com/s/jxjj8qmokqo6oth9p8k9vtgqj7gt740z)
- [VehiclePositions_Benchmark](https://app.box.com/s/8cxvwg4ni904yfu268cw37d5xv1gga7a)

The structure of the binary data file is as follows:

```
PositionId = Int32
VehicleRegistration = Null Terminated ASCII String
Latitude = Float(4 byte floating - point number)
Longitude Float(4 byte floating - point number)
RecordedTimeUTC = UInt64(number of seconds since Epoch)
```

The 10 coordinates to find the closed vehicle positions to are as follows:

- Position 1: Latitude = 34.544909 Longitude = -102.100843
- Position 2: Latitude = 32.345544 Longitude = -99.123124
- Position 3: Latitude = 33.234235 Longitude = -100.214124
- Position 4: Latitude = 35.195739 Longitude = -95.348899
- Position 5: Latitude = 31.895839 Longitude = -97.789573
- Position 6: Latitude = 32.895839 Longitude = -101.789573
- Position 7: Latitude = 34.115839 Longitude = -100.225732
- Position 8: Latitude = 32.335839 Longitude = -99.992232
- Position 9: Latitude = 33.535339 Longitude = -94.792232
- Position 10: Latitude = 32.234235 Longitude = -100.22222

What I have tried:

My code:

```
using MixTest1.Models;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


//list with coordinates
List < CarPosition > coords = new List < CarPosition > {
    new CarPosition {
        position = 1, longitude = 34.544909 f, Latitude = -102.100843 f
    },
    new CarPosition {
        position = 1, longitude = 32.345544 f, Latitude = -99.123124 f
    },
    new CarPosition {
        position = 1, longitude = 33.234235 f, Latitude = -100.214124 f
    },
    new CarPosition {
        position = 1, longitude = 35.195739 f, Latitude = -95.348899 f
    },
    new CarPosition {
        position = 1, longitude = 31.895839 f, Latitude = -97.789573 f
    },
    new CarPosition {
        position = 1, longitude = 32.895839 f, Latitude = -101.789573 f
    },
    new CarPosition {
        position = 1, longitude = 34.115839 f, Latitude = -100.225732 f
    },
    new CarPosition {
        position = 1, longitude = 32.335839 f, Latitude = -99.992232 f
    },
    new CarPosition {
        position = 1, longitude = 33.535339 f, Latitude = -94.792232 f
    },
    new CarPosition {
        position = 1, longitude = 32.234235 f, Latitude = -100.222222 f
    },
    new CarPosition {
        position = 1, longitude = 34.544909 f, Latitude = -102.100843 f
    }
};


var coord = (dynamic) null;

coords.ForEach(x => {
    coord = new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.longitude);
});

StreamReader objInput = new
StreamReader(@ "C:\Users\Downloads\VehiclePositions_DataFile\VehiclePositions.dat",
    System.Text.Encoding.Default);
string contents = objInput.ReadToEnd().Trim();
string[] split = Regex.Split(contents, "\\s+", RegexOptions.None);
int count = 1;
List < CarInfo > carInfos = new List < CarInfo > ();

CarInfo c = new CarInfo();

foreach(string s in split) {
    c.positionId = Convert.ToInt32(s);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    count++;
}

//var nearest = carInfos.Select(x => new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.longitude))
//                       .OrderBy(x => x.(coord))
//                       .First();


//The coord to compare
//var startPoint = new { Latitude = 1.123, Longitude = 12.3 };

//var closest = entities.Something.OrderBy(x => 12742 * SqlFunctions.Asin(SqlFunctions.SquareRoot(SqlFunctions.Sin(((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * (x.Latitude - startPoint.Latitude)) / 2) * SqlFunctions.Sin(((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * (x.Latitude - startPoint.Latitude)) / 2) +
//                                    SqlFunctions.Cos((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * startPoint.Latitude) * SqlFunctions.Cos((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * (x.Latitude)) *
//
```

Answer (score 1):

The main step here, then, appears to be parsing the binary file (with some basic trigonometry). I'm not going to write this for you, but the first step here: forget `BinaryReader`. That isn't what you want here. Stick with `Stream` or similar. So; let's read the protocol specification:

> The structure of the binary data file is as follows:
>
> - PositionId = Int32
> - VehicleRegistration = Null Terminated ASCII String
> - Latitude = Float(4 byte floating - point number)
> - Longitude Float(4 byte floating - point number)
> - RecordedTimeUTC = UInt64(number of seconds since Epoch)

If I was being pedantic, I would complain that the specification is incomplete - it hasn't indicated endianness of the integers, so you'll have to guess. I'd start with little-endian, but:

1. read 4 bytes; run it through `BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian`
2. scan and buffer data until you find a `nul` (byte 0); discard the `nul`, interpret the buffered data via `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`
3. read 4 bytes, run it through `ReadSingleLittleEndian`
4. read 4 bytes, run it through `ReadSingleLittleEndian`
5. read 8 bytes; run it through `BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt64LittleEndian`
6. EOF or repeat

That's your parsing logic. Note: using `SqlFunctions` seems odd here, compared to just `Math`.